# What different title screens are there in the game?

Tags: nier-automata

> After completing ending E and opting to delete all my save data and upon restarting the game,

I realized that my title screen's background had changed to a black screen with 2B's sword and 9S's pack. Are there other title screen backgrounds I can unlock? If so, how do I get them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be a total of three title screen backgrounds.

The default title screen looks like this:

[image: default title screen]

If you

> achieve ending [B] (complete the game as 9S),

then you will unlock this title screen:

> [image: lunar tear title screen]

However, once you achieve ending [E]

> *and* choose to delete all save data,

your title screen will change to this one:

> [image: ending E title screen]

From what I have found online, you cannot manually change them and, going down the list, each title screen appears to replace any previous one, which means unlocking the final one will make that your title screen permanently from that point forward.

Comment: Unless I happened upon some bug, that second one has some sort of different unlocking mechanism than what you said. I did not even start that side quest until after I beat all the major endings, yet I had(have) the second one for quite a while now. I can't say for sure, but I thought I got it simply after the first major ending. I distinctly remember not understanding what the screen was for, and then finally doing that side quest and being like "ohhh, that's what it is".

Comment: @Tylor I beat the side quest before finishing route B and my title screen changed, so perhaps there are multiple ways to unlock it. Will look into this.

Comment: @Tylor I found a place that says finishing Route B will unlock it, but I'm SURE I got it after that side quest. Let me verify if both can unlock it and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Totally makes sense to me that it would unlock as soon as you do the sidequest, as an option to getting it after some endings. 
As an aside, is it possible to grab a shot of the title screen without the menu/'press any button' showing for the 3rd title screen like you have for the first? That would make a pretty sweet wallpaper.

Comment: @Tylor if it's possible for the first, I don't see it wouldn't be possible for the others... are you requesting that I take another picture and replace the one in my answer?